# Visual Studio Code javac cannot be found or is written wrong

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javac, vscode-code-runner

I wanted to know how I can solve this issue. I changed the environment variables to the JDK version I have installed and can check within the command line with `javac -version` if it is installed and it says yes.

Now I don't know how I can fix this problem I changed the json.file in file > preferences > settings. Or in the file settings and inserted `"java.home": "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-11.0.2`", when I downloaded all the extensions visible in the picture below.

How can I fix this to output code with the Code Runner extension?

[Visual studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lzXY.png)

Answer (score 1):

VS Code doesn't recognize whether system environment variable is changed or not until reboot your system.

Or if **Run as administrator** VS code, your command line in VS Code works properly .